# Output from shell command in PHP cli script

Tags: php, command-line-interface

How does one output the contents of a shell script executed from php in realtime?

Say I call scriptA from scriptB; how can I output the results of A before the script is finished?

Script A:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
  echo $i;
  sleep(1);
}
```

Script B:

```
<?php
exec('php /path/to/scriptA.php', $output);

foreach ($output as $line) {
  // This will only output when script A completes.
  echo $line . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprisingly complicated. Rather than use `exec` you'll want to look at `proc_open`.

This worked for me:

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush();

$command = "php /path/to/scriptA";

$descriptors = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("pipe", "w")
);

$pipes = [];
$process = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes, dirname(__SCRIPT__), []);
if (is_resource($process)) {
  $char = '';
  while (($char = fgetc($pipes[1])) !== false) {
    echo $char;
    flush();
  }

  fclose($pipes[0]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);
}
```

Comment: I suppressed them because I was getting `PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush` warnings, but I've just realized that I don't need the hack.